# Could a third stage be added to Starship?

Tags: low-earth-orbit, spacex-starship, payload, stages, refueling

SpaceX has predicted that Starship will be able to lift up to 150 tons to LEO. Could some of the payload that it will carry have a third stage? If so could that save another flight of Starship since then Starship would not need to get refueled in LEO.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## Technically, yes. But not really.

From the [Starship user manual](https://www.spacex.com/media/starship_users_guide_v1.pdf), the payload bay of Starship is 8 meters wide and 17.24 meters tall, with an option for an extended 22-meter fairing. In terms of length, this is pretty similar to the Space Shuttle's 18.3-meter long, 4.6-meter wide cargo bay.

I came up with probably the only useful application of an extra stage on Starship - Centaur. This is because other stages will not provide a useful amount of delta-v for deep-space payloads. While other stages like Delta-K can be useful due to storability, it is small enough to fit as a secondary payload (rideshare capability?!), while the Centaur could be fitted to boost a payload to even higher-energy destinations.

The main plus about this is that Starship can carry a Centaur III (23 tons, 3m diameter, 12.68m length) and some more into GTO with extra delta-v to spare, so maybe a Centaur with payload could be lifted to TLI with a Starship without refueling.

However, there are a few drawbacks to this option. First of all, Centaur and Starship belong to two different companies, ULA and SpaceX, respectively, and commercial cooperation is difficult when there is no mediator (like NASA). Aside from business regards, it would be difficult to fuel the Centaur while it is in the payload fairing, so fuel boiloff would be a major problem should Centaur be fueled prior to encapsulation (safety hazard!). However, if a Starship-Centaur is needed, SpaceX probably should just build a variant of the Starship specifically designed to accommodate a Centaur (or of course, some other cryogenic stage).

Overall, there isn't really a point in putting an extra stage on Starship as it could be refueled (expending the first Starship, probably). If SpaceX does choose to add a third stage, it most likely would be either a collaboration with ULA (Centaur) or the company developing a high-energy upper-stage similar to the Centaur, but development costs will be very high so it is not economically feasible.

Answer (score 2):

Starship is targeting 100-150 t of payload and has a sizable payload volume, so it certainly could carry a third stage. However, this would come at a cost of part of that payload mass and volume, and of adding a large piece of expendable hardware.

Starship is designed to take advantage of orbital propellant transfer. One tanker launch will greatly extend its range of accessible orbits, without expending any hardware or requiring any new stages to be developed and provisions made for safely loading and unloading whatever propellant they need. It's not intended to be some unusual operation that they will take exceptional measures to avoid.

If a third stage is used, it likely won't be to save a tanker flight, but to save a Starship that would otherwise be difficult to recover, for example on a far interplanetary launch. Even in this case, though, you have to compare the cost and limitations of developing a third stage that fits within the cargo hold and competes with the payload for mass and volume, and using an expendable Starship which would just be a simplified version of what's already in serial production.

Answer (score 1):

Pretty much any GEO mission launched on Starship is going to need something to get to GEO.  Thus the third stage will come with the payload at a minimum.  (Short of some kind of refueling mission and then using Starship to boost to a GEO transfer orbit.  Which is probably not very likely).

So in that technical sense, yes. What you more likely intended was a more 'formal' third stage and that is yet to see.  But I suspect most will be carried inside the upper stage, released and used after release.

Answer (score 0):

The number of flights to refuel Starship to get to the moon and back are significant, numbering from a low of 5 or so to as many as 20 (launch to portable fuel depot, launch the lunar Starship, and however many Starships it takes to fuel up the depot (considerable due to boil off). The depot would be reusable, so for the later missions it would not be counted.

It seems to me if an intermediate stage were developed out of the existing Starship design, eliminating the payload area in favor of more fuel, moving the forward flaps back, getting rid of the conical nose, and I'm sure there are other required mods, then the intermediate stage could be reusable. The amount of fuel on it, I think, would be equivalent to the amount on the refueling depot. There would be no need to worry about boil off (or little need). The Starship (now the 3rd stage) would be propelled to the speeds to accomplish all Artemis moon missions. The midstage would have similar costs to the fuel depot.

One big drawback I see is the gigantic length of the total rocket. Bending moments could be considerable. Hot staging between the booster and the intermediate stage may no longer be feasible. But the way IFT1 held together despite all the sideways moments, I tend to believe this is doable.

I'm not a rocket scientist, although I did write flight simulators for NASA, Boeing, and the Marines (one rocket and two high performance jets).

I'm sure SpaceX has thought of this and has their reasons why not to do it, but a layman like me doesn't see them.

-justin